# syntax highlighting for react code in sublime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

I'm started writing some basic React code in sublime text. Here is what my syntax highlighting looks like. Its partly highlighted. Is there any suggested sublime plugin i can use to see a complete syntax highlight?

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'   // <-- is the glue between react and redux
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { selectBook } from '../actions/index'

// there is no intrinsic connection between React and Redux
// they are two seperate libraries
// they are connected using a seperate library called ReactRedux

// container? its a React component that hasa direct connection to state managed by Redux
class BookList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        //this.props = props;
    }

    renderList() {
        return this.props.books.map((book) => {
            return (
                <li key={book.title} className="list-group-item">{book.title}</li>
            )
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul className="list-group col-sm-4">
                {this.renderList()}
            </ul>
        )
    }

}

// function is the glue between react and redux
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    // Whatever gets retrieved from here will show up as props inside
    // of book-list

    return {
        books: state.books
    }
}

// anything returned from this function will end up as props on the BookList container
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({selectBook: selectBook}, dispatch)
}

// Promote BookList from a component to a container - it needs to know
// about this new dispatch method, selectBook. Make it available as a prop
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookList);
```

EDIT: [Fixed some incorrect syntax, Added code text]

Comment: I think there might be a problem in your code, You might have forgotten to close some tag or anything else.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Installing babel fixes the syntax highlighting.

#### Steps to install babel on sublime3:

1. **For windows:** Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> **For mac:** <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Then **type** `install` and **select** `Package control: Install Package`
3. Then **type** `Babel` and **select** `'Babel-Snippets'`. It will install babel in few moments.
4. Then **set the Babel syntax** in Sublime3 Editor **from**: `View > Syntax > Babel > Javascript`

For some users, `Babel` was missing in step 4. They can **additionally install** `Babel` by following the same steps and selecting `Babel` this time  instead of `Babel-Snippets` in step3.

Check I tested it:

[image]

Comment: thanks. actually i was confused because the babel package is not called Babel but called Babel-Snippets. In anycase, it worked for me.

Comment: The same. I've installed Babel-Snippets and followed instructions - fixed.

Comment: For mac users to open the command palette, it's `cmd + shift + p`

Comment: It worked with the `Babel` plugin for me. With the `Babel Snippets` plugin the Babel syntax didn't appear on the list. I'm using Sublime Text 3 over Windows.

Comment: After I install Babel-Snippets, "Babel" is missing from the Syntax menu.  I installed regular "Babel" and then I got a Babel option in the Syntax menu.  Should I be satisfied with this or is Babel-Snippets better?

Comment: Babel is missing from syntax after Babel-Snippets installation. Installed the Babel and it work.

Comment: Step 4 above was the missing piece for me. 
Didn't realise I had to tell it to use Babel
Thank you!

Comment: View > Syntax > Open All with current Extension As...> Babel > Javascript allows you to use this every time you open this type of file

Comment: try after install both Babel & Babel Snippets

Comment: It works for me

Answer (score 5):

You need to install `babel-sublime` plugin.

You can install it from `package control` of sublime.

Here is the link - https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime

Comment: i dont see the 'Babel' option in my package manager. Did you install this manually?

Comment: Well it is for sublime 3.

Comment: Do you have sublime text 2?

Comment: I have sublime3. As i mentioned in  above comment, the package is not called Babel but called Babel-Snippets.

Comment: Note that you still have to 'activate' the plugin by selecting View -> Syntax -> Babel -> Javascript as mentioned in above.

Answer (score 4):

- Step 1 -  Go to Package Control ( <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>)
- Step 2 -  Select install package
- Step 3 -  Search for JSX plugin and install it.
- Step 4 -  Then set the JSX syntax in Sublime3 Editor from: View > Syntax > JSX.

Use filename with  `.jsx` extension

Answer (score 2):

1- Go to package control
2- Search for naomi-syntax and install it.
3- Then set the naomi-syntax syntax in Sublime3 Editor
from: View > Syntax > naomi-syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by setting the syntax to JSX. I didn't need to install this plugin.

Comment: JSX is better than JS for this but the Babel plugin handles many cases better, e.g. for something like `<Input onChange={input.onChange} placeholder={'Type here'} />`, JSX syntax highlighting treats the whole of `placeholder={'Input your email'}` like a string, while Babel plugin highlights it correctly

Comment: How to set the syntax?