# Redux- HTML tags not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using Sublime Text 3 as my editor and am currently working with redux. The html code that is passed in as a component doesn't seem to work. The closing h1 tag in the index.js is not detected instead it seems to comment it out.

Index.js is as follows

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import promise from 'redux-promise';

ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hey there</h1>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

The index.html is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React Webpack</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="js/bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong with the code or are there any changes I need to make in the editor settings?

Edit:
I have also tried running the code on the server using npm start run and the html part of the code indicates that it is a syntax error. The exact error is as follows:

```
ERROR in ./dev/js/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (12:16)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [syntax highlighting for react code in sublime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319547/syntax-highlighting-for-react-code-in-sublime)

Comment: it's not possible to answer in detail, without any background, like Webpack/Babel configs and packages.json (I suggest you use one, as `npm run start` is doing smth). Could you provide a link to the whole repo of this product you're writing ? Otherwise, I'd suggest using Babel preset for React, it's necessary (AFAIK) in order for JSX syntax to be transpiled correctly

Comment: By the way, this problem has NOTHING TO DO AT ALL with Redux

Comment: I am learning from the following repo, https://github.com/buckyroberts/React-Redux-Boilerplate    I ran the code but got the error on the html tags which are not being recognised and give the unexpected token error. I added a simple h1 tag in index.html and it works fine so there is no problem with the server...

Answer (score 0):

Unexpected token means you have something wrong in your code. Try:

```
ReactDOM.render("<h1>Hey there</h1>",document.getElementById("root"));
```

or

```
const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Tried it out, doesn't work, The first example doesn't print anything to the webpage although it gets rid of the error whereas the second one results in the same Unexpected token error.