# syntax highlighting error of jsx in sublime text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sublimetext3

I am trying to construct react components in sublime text, but the syntax highlighting is suggesting that I didn't do everything properly. Where is wrong?
[image: syntax highlight]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [syntax highlighting for react code in sublime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319547/syntax-highlighting-for-react-code-in-sublime)

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely using the Javascript syntax definition, which does not recognize inline HTML like this. To fix this, try the [`JSX.sublime-syntax`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sublimehq/Packages/master/JavaScript/JSX.sublime-syntax) definition from Sublime Text 4, which is in development now.

To install it, copy the `.sublime-syntax` file from the above link to your `Packages/User` directory, where `Packages` is the one opened when selecting **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`**:

- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`
- OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`
- Windows Regular Install: `C:\Users<b>YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages`
- Windows Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages`

You will also want to place the [`JSX Comments.tmPreferences`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sublimehq/Packages/master/JavaScript/JSX%20Comments.tmPreferences) file in the same directory so that comments work properly.

To use the new JSX syntax highlighting, select **`View → Syntax → User → JSX`**. Files with the `.jsx` suffix should be opened with the correct syntax automatically.